# I have a solar powered keyboard

Tags: battery-operated

I'm no engineer and am no electronics type person at all.

I friend suggested I post my question here.

I have a solar powered keyboard that uses an ML2032 3v lithium battery. I ordered a new one and received an LIR2032 3.6v battery.

Will the higher voltage battery give me problems?

thanks for your patience with me. :)

Comment: You better check (or post) the specs of the keyboard. Or even ask it's manufacturer.

Comment: What brand/model of keyboard is it?

Answer (score 2):

An ML2032 is Manganese Dioxide based Litium Chemistry, whereas LIR2032 is traditional Lithium Ion.

The voltage difference may not be important to the Keyboard, but the fact they have vastly different charge and discharge curves most certainly will, since with a solar cell (how rare!?) the charging circuitry must be internal to the keyboard.

The ML2032 is full at 3.3-ish volts and empty at 2.0-ish volts. The LIR will not even be half full when charged to 3.3V, and will be much below its safest lower limit at 2.0V.